# Case statement for Repo Query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a cronjob that runs a function at 9:00pm every night. The first thing this function does is make a ecto query. But, there is a chance that the query comes back empty. I want to be able to handle this case if it happens.

#### CURRENT ATTEMPT:

```
def check_question(conn, _params) do
  case Repo.get_by(Question, active: true, closed: true) do

  question ->

  _ ->

  end
end
```

But this doesn't work because if the query is nil then it throws this error:

#### ERROR:

```
function nil.game_id/0 is undefined or private
```

It's basically trying to check the nil question in the next function but obviously it breaks because the question is nil.

How can I route it to the _ case if the repo query comes back nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case will try to match from top to bottom. So in your code, first try to match nil and then the case when it is not. OR use `when not is_nil(question)` if you want to match case when result is not nil

```
def check_question(conn, _params) do
  case Repo.get_by(Question, active: true, closed: true) do

  question when not(is_nil(question)) ->

  _ ->

  end
end
```

OR without `when`

```
def check_question(conn, _params) do
  case Repo.get_by(Question, active: true, closed: true) do
   nil -> ... case when result is nil
  question ->
     ... case when there is result
  end
end
```

One more thing, whenever you write case without any decomposition or boolean check it is same as you math `_ -> ...` expression. Difference between `_` and `question` is only in that you don't want to assign matched value to local variable. So in your attempt, `_ ->` will NEVRER match since `question -> ...` will ALWAYS match, and both cases are actually the same expression. You probably could see that as warning in console when you try to compile that file. So always try to decompose and check/match some value in expression!